# Can't define custom scalar in Apollo GraphQL, have some issues with TypeScript typing

Tags: typescript, graphql, typescript-typings, apollo-server

I'm trying to implement this example in TypeScript: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/custom-scalars#example-the-date-scalar

```
import { GraphQLScalarType, Kind } from 'graphql';

export const dateScalar = new GraphQLScalarType({
    name: 'Date',
    description: 'Date custom scalar type',
    serialize(value: Date) {
        return value.getTime(); // Convert outgoing Date to integer for JSON
    },
    parseValue(value: number) {
        return new Date(value); // Convert incoming integer to Date
    },
    parseLiteral(ast) {
        if (ast.kind === Kind.INT) {
            // Convert hard-coded AST string to integer and then to Date
            return new Date(parseInt(ast.value, 10));
        }
        // Invalid hard-coded value (not an integer)
        return null;
    },
});
```

but have some TypeScript errors:

```
src/graphql-scalars/date-scalar.ts:6:5 - error TS2322: Type '(value: Date) => number' is not assignable to type 'GraphQLScalarSerializer<number>'.
  Types of parameters 'value' and 'outputValue' are incompatible.
    Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Date': toDateString, toTimeString, toLocaleDateString, toLocaleTimeString, and 37 more.

6     serialize(value: Date) {
      ~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/graphql/type/definition.d.ts:363:3
    363   serialize?: GraphQLScalarSerializer<TExternal>;
          ~~~~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'serialize' which is declared here on type 'Readonly<GraphQLScalarTypeConfig<Date, number>>'
```

Just new in TypeScript and can't understand where (how) do I define (extends) these types?

Comment: Looking at the [source](https://github.com/Urigo/graphql-scalars) from the graphql-scalars package might help - it's all ts.

Comment: I encountered this error when I enabled the `strict` property in tsconfig.json (compilerOptions.strict = true).  If you can get away with it, you can disable that property (remove it or set it to false.). I have not yet figured out how to make it not complain with strict mode enabled.

Answer (score -1):

Added a comment but found the solution as well.

I encountered this error after turning on strict type checking in the tsconfig.json (setting compilerOptions.strict = true).  You can either disable strict type checking or read on for the solution using strict type checking.

the declaration for `serialize` is actually:

```
serialize: GraphQLScalarSerializer<TExternal>
```

and the type of `GraphQLScalarSerializer` is:

```
declare type GraphQLScalarSerializer<TExternal> = (
  outputValue: unknown
) => TExternal;
```

which means your serialize function is not following the definition.  It should be:

```
serialize(value: unknown) {
    return (value as Date).getTime(); // Convert outgoing Date to integer for JSON
}
```

for future readers, the types from above are declared in the npm package graphql@16.6.0